# Click using SetCursorPos and mouse_event strange behavior

Tags: c#, winapi, mouseevent

I have this code for click anywhere in the screen :

```
    public static void Click(Point coords)
    {
        SetCursorPos(coords.X, coords.Y);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

But it seems that sometimes (but I can reproduce the behavior) the click happens before the SetCursorPos, at the previous pos of the mouse.

I don't know where the problem is, but it seems to happen after an intensive usage of SetCursorPos.

Anyone know the issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Teleporting the mouse isn't a great idea.  You ought to use MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE so the app can actually see it move.

Comment: yes but MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE can't handle secondary screen

Comment: That's news to me, pretty sure it can.  mouse_event() is deprecated, you should be using SendInput().

Comment: I test with SendInput, I will update this post

Comment: Hi, I use SendInput for mouse move and click, same issue.
I keep looking in my code for a mistake.